# как растянуть изображение?

Tags: html, css

на маленьких экранах,сайт выглядит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с белой полосой внизу

код background:

```
.body{
font-family: 'Sora',Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background-image: url('../../images/6-konechn-black.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
.body{
font-family: 'Sora',Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background-image: url('../../images/6-konechn-black.jpg') 50% / cover no-repeat fixed;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]